# VMware Workstation Server 12 shared virtual machines not working

Tags: vmware-workstation

I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 and VMware Workstation Server 12, in Workstation Server 11, shared VMs worked fine out of the box but in this new version it just doesn't work, I can login to the server and everything but the "New Virtual Machine" button and the "Share" menu entry don't do a thing.

Am I missing a step here? I just reinstalled the OS and VMware and the issue persists.

Comment: What is "Workstation Server 12" and "Workstation Server 11"?

Comment: it's a feature on plain 'ol VMware Workstation, it can run as a server (you can "share" virtual machines to be available even if a user hasn't logged in). This feature replaced the old VMware Server.